# How to use System.Drawing.Pen?

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls, system.drawing

I am in need of creating a custom form which look same as the Microsoft form by default.

Currently I am working on the title bar buttons customization.

For that I have used the graphics methods to draw the buttons.

Please find the code that I have used to draw the maximize button.

```
g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Black), maxIconRect);
```

But I am not able to get the exact appearance of the Microsoft form.

In the below image the 1st one is the title bar created by me. 2nd one is the title bar of Microsoft form.

[image: Caption bar]

You can see the difference in the maximize and minimize button. The thickness and clarity of the buttons are different for these two forms.

I have tried to specify the width of the pen as given below.

```
Var pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 0.5F);
```

But there is no different in the appearance.

Can you please provide your suggestion to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, for which OS, you are developing this tool?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the pen. The difference relates to the question of the program being "dpi aware". Search Stack Overflow for that topic to see what's needed in your program to make it dpi-aware, so that Windows will let your program draw at the actual screen resolution, instead of having it draw at a lower resolution and then scaling the output up to fit the screen.

Comment: It is for windows 10.

Comment: Thanks for your update.@PeterDuniho